# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'bootstrapDatepicker'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I see a lot of 'Uncaught TypeError' But none of the answers has helped.

It looks like it is something between tribe-events-ajax-calendar.js and foundation.min.js

If I remove foundation.min.js the datepicker works with no errors but when I put it back in I get the errors. Here is what my chrome inspector shows:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method
>   'bootstrapDatepicker' tribe-events-ajax-calendar.js:42
>
> (anonymous function) tribe-events-ajax-calendar.js:42
>
> l foundation.min.js:18
>
> c.fireWith foundation.min.js:18
>
> y.extend.ready foundation.min.js:18`enter code here`

it breaks on this line(42) in tribe-events-ajax-calendar.js

> var tribeBarDate =
>   $tribedate.bootstrapDatepicker(tribe_var_datepickerOpts).on('changeDate',
>   function (e) {

[Here is the page](http://junknlove.fervorinteractive.com/events/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to include the bootsrap datepicker js after the foundation.js file

Comment: like `<script src="http://junknlove.fervorinteractive.com/wp-content/themes/jnl/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://junknlove.fervorinteractive.com/wp-content/themes/jnl/js/jquery.foundation.orbit.js"></script>
<script src="http://junknlove.fervorinteractive.com/wp-content/themes/jnl/js/jquery.foundation.accordion.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://junknlove.fervorinteractive.com/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js?ver=3.2'></script>`

Comment: Oh man... Thanks!! You rock. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks again!!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the bootsrap datepicker js after the foundation.js file

like

```
<script src="http://junknlove.fervorinteractive.com/wp-content/themes/jnl/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://junknlove.fervorinteractive.com/wp-content/themes/jnl/js/jquery.foundation.orbit.js"></script>
<script src="http://junknlove.fervorinteractive.com/wp-content/themes/jnl/js/jquery.foundation.accordion.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://junknlove.fervorinteractive.com/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js?ver=3.2'></script>
```